# nvd3 is there existing way to add a scroller to nvd3 chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using a nvd3 chart, but if I have a lot of data which is bigger than the chart container's width there is no scroller and I can't find a way to add it.

http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/cumulativeLineChart

I tried to add `overflow:scroll`
to the `div.chartwrapper` wrapper.

```
<div class="chartwrapper" ng-app="app-origin" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <nvd3 options="options2" data="data2"></nvd3>
 </div>
```

and to the chart itself

```
<nvd3 options="options2" data="data2" class="ng-isolate-scope"><svg height="450px" width="100%"
```

How can I add a scroller to the chart to see all the data I inserted to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can to use a pair of divs, using fixed width, for example, to define the scroll:

at html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="inner"></nvd3>
  </div>
</div>
```

at css:

```
div.outer { overflow: scroll; }
div.outer .inner { width: 1024px; }
```

see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jmkioVrVhqOBsyTbffGw?p=preview) based on original sample

Comment: I try to do it and its work, the problem is when i try to set its width dynamically document.getElementByClass("inner").style.width = numofPeoples * 200000 + "px"; then the chart's width doesnt updated

Comment: Use this: document.getElementsByClassName('inner')[0].style.width = numofPeoples * 200000 + "px"; Don't forget to test if numofPeoples variable is correct